# Set ng-model dynamically without populating the textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="selectedColumn in SelectedListItems" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">{{selectedColumn.column}}</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input ng-model="selectedColumn.column" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The SelectedListItems is:

```
$scope.SelectedListItems = [
        { column: 'Description' },
        { column: 'Colour' },
        { column: 'KW/PS' },
        { column: 'Chilometri x 1000 km' },
        { column: 'Reg.' },
        { column: 'Equipment' },
        { column: 'No. PJVA' },
        { column: 'Price' }
    ];
```

For each of those column I want a new textbox. Also, I wanted to set an `ng-model` dynamically for every textbox so that I can use the values that are typed in it.

Now I have two issues:
The textbox is populated with the column value and also the `ng-model` is `selectedColumn.column` in browser when I inspect the textbox, so I can't seem to understand how will I get the values from those textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following .

```
<div ng-repeat="selectedColumn in SelectedListItems" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">{{selectedColumn.column}}</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input ng-model="selectedColumn.textInput" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and can access value like this.

example for description.

```
$scope.SelectedListItems[0].textInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new property for every item in the array and store the value there.

```
$scope.SelectedListItems = [
        { columnName: 'Description', columnValue:'' },
        { columnName: 'Colour', columnValue:'' }      
    ];
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="selectedColumn in SelectedListItems" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">{{selectedColumn.columnName}}</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <input ng-model="selectedColumn.columnValue" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```